# Generated column using string replace function throws a syntax error in SQLite3

Tags: sqlite

I am trying to run the following statement in SQLite3 command line but get an error:

```
create table projects(
  "project_creation_date" TEXT,
  "project_creation_date_formatted" as replace("project_creation_date", "/", "-")
);
```

> Error: near "replace": syntax error

I don't understand why this error occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must enclose the whole expression inside parentheses:

```
create table projects(
  "project_creation_date" TEXT,
  "project_creation_date_formatted" as (replace("project_creation_date", "/", "-"))
);
```

Comment: what determines which expressions must be enclosed in parantheses in sqlite?

Comment: It is about the correct syntax. Check this: https://sqlite.org/gencol.html